# “an jemandes Nerven zehren” – or is it “zerren”?

Tags: etymology, phrase, colloquial

Which of these two verbs is the **historically** correct one in this phrase?

I'm a German living in Germany. The phrase

> an jemandes Nerven zehren/zerren

is often used in modern German and can roughly be translated as:

> to be a pain in the neck
>   to get on so.'s nerves
>   to jangle so.'s nerves

*None* of the many native speakers I asked so far could say without doubt whether the concurring verb actually has to be *zehren* or *zerren*. There's a huge similarity both phonetically and semantically (at least regarding *Nerven*) here:

- *zehren* is (in my perception) rarely used outside this phrase and can be translated as “to gnaw at so.”, “to wear so. out” or “to undermine sth.”
- *zerren* is far more common, translations include “to wrench”, “to jerk” and „to drag“

Both semantics can be easily combined with *Nerven* and the alternation is so widespread that [duden.de](https://www.duden.de/) lists an example sentence for **both** verbs:

> die ständigen Aufregungen zehrten an ihren Nerven [[source](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zehren)]

under the meaning „jemandem sehr zusetzen, sich bei jemandem schädigend auswirken, etwas stark in Mitleidenschaft ziehen“.

> <in übertragener Bedeutung>:
>   der Lärm zerrt an meinen Nerven (ist eine große Belastung für meine Nerven) [[source](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zerren)]

under the meaning „(aus Widerstreben, Unmut, Ungeduld o. Ä.) heftig reißen, ruckartig ziehen“.

See also https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Zusammensetzungen-aus-Nerv-und-Partizip-I.

Comment: If you as linguist can't find a striking argumentation, is this question intended as opinion poll?

Comment: @guidot Maybe I didn't mark it clear enough, but the overall question here is: *Which of these two verbs is the **historically** correct one in this phrase?* I can't help it if I receive opinions as answers here, but this question is not at all opinion-based. I'm moving it to the top of the post now.

Comment: I used to think that _zehren_ is the original and people replace it in the phrase with _zerren_ because outside of this phrase _zehren_ is used (known) less frequently than _zerren_. But that's just my theory...

Comment: I have also heard  the expression er ist eine "Nervensäge"

Answer (score 3):

It is *Nerven zehren*, see [Redensarten-Index](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiy1-_2h8DXAhVDOxoKHfwDDfEQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.redensarten-index.de%2Fsuche.php%3Fsuchbegriff%3D~~an%2520jemandes%2520Nerven%2520zehren%26bool%3Drelevanz%26suchspalte%255B%255D%3Drart_ou&usg=AOvVaw393NPP9qes22WQmDatZkzc).

I would explain it not so much by *nourishing from* in the sense, that something gets stronger by it, but more at *gnawing at* in the sense of eating them away, so little or nothing remains from them.

This is in line with *starke Nerven brauchen* (requiring strong nerves), where *strong* could mean something like durability, but also simply a mechanical thickness, which is reduced by gnawing at them. The same picture is used in *finanzielle Rücklagen aufzehren*.

I would guess that the  combination *Nerven* and *zerren* originates from mixing in a different metaphor, being the translation of *to stress*.

Comment: *An jemandes Nerven zerren* also has an entry there, see [here](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=an+jemandes+Nerven+zerren+&suchspalte[]=rart_ou). From the statistics it's obvious that the *zehren* variant gets more hits, but then again that's only a sign this variant may be considered the correct one among speakers, not which one's the historically correct one. This may very well be a case of [hypercorrection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection)!

Answer (score 3):

I used https://www.dwds.de/r to search different corpora for the phrase, here's what I found (nothing after 1950 included).

#### zehren

1795

> Höchstens im tiefen Schlafe, wo der Nervenkörper ruht, könnte man die Seele vom Irrdischen loßgekettet denken; im Traum hingegen eher enger angeschlossen, weil der Traum so gut wie das tiefe Denken, das wie er die fünf Sinnenpforten abschließt, ja kein Schlafen ist. Daher **zehren Träume die Nerven** so sehr **aus**, zu deren innern Ueberspannungen jene noch äussere Eindrücke gesellen.
> [Paul, Jean: Hesperus, oder 45 Hundsposttage. Drittes Heftlein. Berlin, 1795, S. 244]

1933

> Erkennen Sie lieber die Ursachen ihres Aergers, die Mängel Ihres Blutes, die **an Ihren Nerven zehren**!
> [Berliner Tageblatt (Morgen-Ausgabe), 04.02.1933]

#### zerren

1915

> Marieluis empfand jede wie einen Schmerz - alles **zerrte an ihren Nerven**.
> [Boy-Ed, Ida: Vor der Ehe. In: Deutsche Literatur von Frauen, Berlin: Directmedia Publ. 2001 [1915], S. 8388]

1916

> Dieser Lärm durchbohrt und lähmt unser Gehirn und **zerrt an unsere** [sic] **Nerven**.
> [Berliner Tageblatt (Morgen-Ausgabe), 01.03.1916]

1917

> Ich vertrag viel, aber eine schiefe Situation, das ist mir etwas so Odioses, das **zerrt** direkt **an meinen Nerven**.
> [Hofmannsthal, Hugo von: Der Schwierige. In: Deutsche Literatur von Lessing bis Kafka, Berlin: Directmedia Publ. 2000 [1917], S. 92546]

1922

> Bahr, der immer noch lebt, bis zu jenem Mahrholz, der scheint's unter denen, **die an unsern Nerven zerren**, den Ehrgeiz hat, den ersten Platz sich zu erschreiben, unterstützt von dem nicht zu zählenden Schwarm von redefixen Schwammerln, die plötzlich über Nacht aufschießen aus dem Boden der "Bildung", sobald ihn einer mit was immer von neuem benäßt hat.
> [Haecker, Theodor: Satire und Polemik. Innsbruck, 1922, S. 219]

1924

> Und man fühlt in Paris nach einiger Zeit, wenn man gemerkt hat, daß einem keiner **an den Nerven zerrt**, daß alles glatt und angenehm vonstatten geht, daß das Dasein gleitet und nicht hakt - man empfindet, wie einfach im Grunde das Leben ist.
> [Tucholsky, Kurt: Das menschliche Paris. In: ders., Kurt Tucholsky, Werke - Briefe - Materialien, Berlin: Directmedia Publ. 2000 [1924], S. 3058]

1925

> Und schrecklich mischen sich mir die Belanglosigkeiten, von denen ich lese, mit den **nervenzerrenden** Ereignissen meiner Umwelt.
> [Kisch, Egon Erwin: Der rasende Reporter, Berlin: Aufbau-Taschenbuch-Verl. 2001 [1925], S. 331]

+ 5 more

#### Conclusion

It's hard to say from this evidence:

- *zehren* is much earlier attested, but only once and as ***aus**zehren*, after that it occurs only **once** until 1950
- *zerren* is first attested only 1915, but in exchange at least 11 times until 1950

The little evidence for *zehren* however is remarkable and doesn't really support the seemingly popular claim of *zehren* as the “traditional” or historically correct choice.

Answer (score 2):

*zehren von* is "to be nourishing from". It is rarely the case that something that annoys you is nourishing from that annoyance. So "... zehrt von meinen Nerven" is somewhat off and it should rather be "zehren an".

*zehren an* means, in comparison, "wear sb./sth. out" - This means something is wearing out your nerves and grinds it to nothing. Fits very well to "zehrt an meinen Nerven".

"zerren an" rather means "to physically pull on something". That would literally mean someone pulls your nerves (ouch, that hurts). I'd rather not use that.

I am pretty sure even native speakers mess this up every now and then.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I take it this reflects your personal opinion. While I appreciated it I was hoping for a more objective answer shedding some light on the historical situation, see the actual question at the end of my posting.